# Trying to install Elm using Windows subsystem for Linux

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm-install, elm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Trying to install Elm on Windows Ubuntu, but getting the the error below

Tried running npm install -g elm got permission errors, even after using administrator

```
XXXX:~$ npm install -g elm
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules
```

```
XXXX:~$ elm -v
/mnt/c/Users/Lenovo/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/elm/bin/elm:1
ELF
^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Expecting Elm to install, I believe it should have installed together with Node

[image: Image here]

Comment: Which version of node?

Comment: The version is v10.16.2

Comment: Try using NVM to install Node/NPM. If that doesn't work, you might need to change the install location. See this help article: https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

Comment: I believe that's solved some of the problem elm folders are added to \LocalState\rootfs\home\<user>\.npm-global but now I cant access the \LocalState\rootfs root because of permissions. I tried sudo su and that still didn't work. I believe this is why 'elm, elm -v, which elm' commands aren't working. I can't check if it's installed correctly without these.